# SpeechBackground

Tags: asterisk, voice-recognition

Hai everyone,

I have used the SpeechBackground application in asterisk. I used the version 1.6.0.6.

I have a entry like,

```
;;SpeechCreate

exten => s,1,SpeechCreate()
exten => s,2,SpeechActivateGrammar(yesno)
exten => s,3,SpeechStart()
exten => s,4,SpeechBackground(demo-instruct)
exten => s,5,SpeechDeactivateGrammar(yesno)
```

I don't know which file I meed to give in SpeechBackground application. Please give me any idea. I have given the sound file from /sounds directory.

If I call to 's' the call will be immediately released.I didn't get any audio sound.
Please any one help me...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that you have `Answer()`'d the channel.

```
;; SpeechCreate

exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,n,SpeechCreate()
exten => s,n,SpeechActivateGrammar(yesno)
exten => s,n,SpeechStart()
exten => s,n,SpeechBackground(demo-instruct)
exten => s,n,SpeechDeactivateGrammar(yesno)
```